# Check Zend Registry variable inside htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I want to write htaccess redirect rule on the base of value inside Zend_Registry variable

Something like this

```
if(Zend_Registry::get('country') == 'uk'){

     RewriteRule (.+).html /abc/page/directory/abc/view/$1 [L]

}elseif(Zend_Registry::get('country') == 'ca'){

     RewriteRule (.+).html /xyz/static/directory/xyz/view/$1 [L]
}
```

Thank You in adavance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but you can't do what you are asking. When Apache serves the page, it consults .htaccess before it hands off to the PHP processor, inside of which your application (and `Zend_Registry`) resides.

You need to handle all this *inside the app* using ZF's [standard routing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html).

If, however, your country values are detectable from the host name or from the requested url itself, then you can use standard `.htaccess` RewriteRules, no `Zend_Registry` involved or required.

Comment: I just found out. I can use Zend _forward utility to solve this issue without touching .htaccess file. Thank You.